# Is there any better way to get header and footer data from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

[image]

The image is the design of my homepage. 
There will be about 100 pages for this website. 
My Clients want an admin page(different domain) from where he can edit data in header and footer.
So if I fetch header and footer data from the database for every page then I think it will not be a proper way to do it and it can make the website slow.
So is there any other way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: cache those parts of the page, and refresh cache if someone updates it in the admin side with new updates

Comment: tbh you are talking milliseconds of a difference for something like a menu (unless it is extremely complex multi-layer).

Comment: Hi, look at this: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-63825.html